# Deserializar un XmlDocument en un tipo especifico desde un XSD

Tags: c#, xml, deserialize

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de C# dónde tengo un documento xml el cual debo deserializarlo con la clase que se encuentra en un XSD el problema es que tengo un error al hacerlo.

Xml que quiero deserializar: [XML string](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x59xnzhzebooe5d/xml.xml?dl=0)

llamo a la deserialización así:

```
object cfe = new object();

Serializacion.Deserializar<Helpers.CFEDefType>(ref ErrorMsg, cteXml, ref cfe);
```

Dónde el código es el siguiente:

```
    public static bool Deserializar<T>(ref string errorMessage, XmlDocument xmlDocument, ref object objetoDeserializado)
        {
            try
            {
                oReply oreply = new oReply();
                oreply = Serializacion.SerializarXML(xmlDocument);
                object objetoDeserializar = new object();
                if (oreply.ErrorCod == 0)
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

                    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)oreply.Reply);
                    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

                    objetoDeserializar = serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                    stream.Close();
                    stream.Dispose();
                }
                objetoDeserializado = objetoDeserializar;
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = ex.Message;
                return false;
            }

        }

El código de Serializacion.SerializarXML(xmlDocument)

public static oReply SerializarXML(XmlDocument documentoXML)
        {
            //SERIALIZO......................................................
            XmlSerializer oXmlSerializar = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlDocument));
            string sXml = "";
            oReply reply = new oReply();
            try
            {
                using (var sww = new StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    using (XmlWriter writter = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
                    {
                        oXmlSerializar.Serialize(writter, documentoXML);
                        sXml = sww.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                reply.ErrorCod = 1;
                reply.ErrorMessage = "No fue posible serializar el XML verifique su estructura - Exception - "
                                        + ex.Message;
                return reply;
            }
            reply.ErrorCod = 0;
            reply.ErrorMessage = "";
            reply.Reply = sXml;
            return reply;
        }
```

La clase que quiero deserializar es un poco larga por lo que les adjunto el link del archivo
[Clase dónde está el CfeDefType](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5wwwgptuwovbs2/CFE.cs?dl=0)

El Mensaje de error que obtengo al hacer objetoDeserializar = serializer.Deserialize(stream);
se produce una exception:

Message = "Error en el documento XML (1, 40)."
InnerException = Message = "No se esperaba ."

Ayuda please

Answer (score 0):

El problema radicaba en varios espacios que tenía el documento xml y lo solucioné así:

```
string cteStr = Serializacion.SerializarXmlToString(cteXml);

public static string SerializarXmlToString<T>(T xmlASerializar)
    {
        //SERIALIZO......................................................
        XmlSerializer oXmlSerializar = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        string sXml = "";
        using (var sww = new StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            using (XmlWriter writter = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
            {
                oXmlSerializar.Serialize(writter, xmlASerializar);
                sXml = sww.ToString();
            }
        }
        return sXml;
    }
```

Eso me devuelve la cadena de texto serializada y sin espacios y en utf8